# Substitute individual characters within matching delimiters in vim

Tags: vim

I have a csv file where some cells contain `,` between `"..."`. I need to change only the commas between the quotation marks to semicolons without the rest of the commas on the line getting replaced.  That is, I have something like this:

```
x,"y,z",a
```

And only the comma between `y` and `z` should be replaced with `;`. How should this be done in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single pair of quotes per line you could use:

```
%s/\v("[^"]*)@<=,(.*")@=/;/g
```

Input:

```
x,"y,z,a",b
```

output:

```
x,"y;z;a",b
```

For more than a pair of quotes per line you could use the following awk command:

```
:!awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", ";", $i) } 1' infile > outfile
```

This command is based on a question in [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/remove-comma-between-the-quotes-only-in-a-comma-delimited-file). It will set a quote `"` as the field separator and substitute commas in every other field using `gsub`.

Comment: and what do you mean by "using a parser"

Answer (score 1):

This vim command `:s` with `substitute()` function call will do the job easily:

```
%s/"\zs[^"]*/\=substitute(submatch(0),',',';','g')
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: I like it a lot, but I noticed it added lines to my file (!). Is that a known effect?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one comma between the double quotes, and no more than one match per line the following substitute command should work:

```
:%s/\(".*\),\(.*"\)/\1;\2/
```